# iOS AppDelegate.mm String literal must be prefixed by '@'

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
  if (appCenterConfig[@"AppSecret"] != "APPCENTER_SECRET") {
    [AppCenterReactNative register];
    [AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics registerWithInitiallyEnabled:true];
    [AppCenterReactNativeCrashes registerWithAutomaticProcessing];
  }
```

I got the following error: String literal must be prefixed by '@'.

How can this issue be fixed? I'm a JS developer and not really familiar with iOS world. I guess `@` should also be provided somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Put an @ before "APPCENTER_SECRET", although this isn't the equality test for strings that you need, so that needs fixing too

Comment: You need to change it to if (!([appCenterConfig[@"AppSecret"] isEqualToString: @"APPCENTER_SECRET"])). because == and != are just comparing pointers and not doing actual string comparison, which is what isEqualToString: is for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literals, including string literals in Objective-C have to be prefixed with @ because the regular "quoted string" already means something else in C, and Objective-C is a superset of C.

`"Thing in quotes"` is a C string.

`@"Thing in quotes"` is a NSString object.

You can't compare NSStrings for equality with `==` or `!=`

Use `[A isEqualToString:B]` for comparing strings